# Moving from Subversion to Git in place

Tags: git, svn

I have a number of client repositories in Subversion that are now being changed to git. The client does not care about the change history, so what I'd like to do is:

- Import/ convert using Bitbucket
- Initialize a git repository in the current svn-controlled folder
- Start using git

Is this possible? Is it going to be a giant pain? The only real reason it matters is because I'd like to do this on the servers as well to avoid having to create a new project on each server and re-point the Apache/ Nginx/ etc configuration files.

Comment: @JimPuls - I looked at that one, but I don't need the history and I don't want to clone a new folder (which it looks like that requires, at least at a glance).

Comment: `rm -rf \`find . -type d -name .svn\` && git init` - only sort of joking

Comment: @tvanfosson That's exactly the answered that uccurs to me, not joking. If you don't want history, that'll do it. But throwing away history seems crazy to me. It sometimes comes in very handy.

Answer (score 1):

"SVN-contollled folder" is too wide definition. Does it means "Working Copy of SVN repository"?

Anyway, in these svn-controlled folders you can

- `git-svn clone -r HEAD:HEAD URL/OF/SVN` in order to get Git-repo from SVN-HEAD without history
- Remove from `.git/config` file `[svn-remote ...]` section (forget about SVN origin)
- Remove `.svn` directory (if it was SVN's Working Copy)
- `git co` in order to get files from index into working tree